# subclassing dataframe with specific columns

Tags: python, pandas, class, dataframe, subclassing

I'm trying to create my own class of Dataframe. I would like it has some specific columns when I call it. So I do this:

```
from pandas import DataFrame

class MyClass(DataFrame):  

    def __init__(self):    
        super(MyClass, self).__init__(columns=['Class','Conditions'])
```

However, when I try to append data to it,

```
test = MyClass()
#test = MyClass(columns=['Class','Conditions'])

test.loc[2] = ['class2',[1, 2, 3]]
```

I get an error:

> File "C:\Miniconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py", line
>   189, in **setitem**
>       self._setitem_with_indexer(indexer, value)
>
> File "C:\Miniconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py", line
>   451, in _setitem_with_indexer
>       self.obj._data = self.obj.append(value)._data
>
> File "C:\Miniconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line
>   6211, in append
>       sort=sort)
>
> File
>   "C:\Miniconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\reshape\concat.py", line
>   226, in concat
>       return op.get_result()
>
> File
>   "C:\Miniconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\reshape\concat.py", line
>   428, in get_result
>       return (cons._from_axes(new_data, self.new_axes)
>
> File "C:\Miniconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py", line
>   356, in _from_axes
>       return cls(data, **kwargs)
>
> TypeError: **init**() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given

I realised if I don't declare the columns in `__init__` and I assign them after the class is created, I have no problem.

However, I would like to class be created with those names as columns.

Thank very much.

Comment: I can't replicate. Can you provide a [mcve] with something runnable in place of `Condition('var2',op.ne,3)` ?

Comment: sorry @jpp my bad. You can replace condition by a list. Like [1,2,3]. I update the example. Thank you. Regards

Comment: Does it need to be a subclass of `DataFrame` - unless you're going to be adding/ overriding methods etc... It kind of looks like you could just do `MyDataFrame = functools.partial(DataFrame, columns=['Class', 'Condtions'])` to fix the column argument for the call and use that?

Comment: @GermánMartínez, Your code works fine for me in v0.19.2. What version are you using?

Comment: Hi @jpp the code works, but I want the columns to be predefined when the object is constructed. Regards

Answer (score 3):

If you want to use the constructor for initialization, you have to pass the arguments to parent `__init__`

```
>>> class MyClass(DataFrame):                                                                                                                                              
        def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):                                                                                                                                   
            kwargs['columns'] = ['Class', 'Conditions']                                                                                                                        
            super(MyClass, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)                                                                                                                     

>>> md = MyClass({'Class': [1, 2, 3]})
>>> md
   Class Conditions
0      1        NaN
1      2        NaN
2      3        NaN
```